# r.js leads to: Evaluating ./lib/jquery.js as module "jquery" failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined

Tags: jquery, requirejs, r.js, requirejs-optimizer

I am trying to use r.js on my code which uses jQuery. But it fails while evaluating jQuery.

This is the error message I get:

> $ r.js init-edx-machine.js 
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:393
>           throw err;
>           ^
>
> Error: Evaluating ./lib/jquery.js as module "jquery" failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
>       at Function.req.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2571:23)
>       at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1935:21)
>       at Module.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1084:29)
>       at Module.fetch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1074:66)
>       at Module.check (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1106:30)
>       at Module.enable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
>       at Object.enable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1807:39)
>       at Module. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1411:33)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
>       at each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)

I've searched for "createElement" in jquery.js. Most of the time it uses document. Sometimes it uses variables which are given through parameters.

The jQuery version is 2.1.4. I checked newer versions, they do it the same.

I really have no clue what is going on here. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `r.js` without an option will make it want to *execute* your code, which is what happens here. You can an error because there's no `document` available globally by default in Node.js (contrarily to browsers), and thus the code fails.

To perform an optimization, you need to pass the `-o` argument: `r.js -o ...`

Comment: Oh damn... I missed that point. I thought "-o" defines the output file.